# Retrieving value from dynamically created text box in php?

Tags: javascript, php

It will create text box with name=id1,id2,id3..... on clicking the add option. 
But when I going to fetch the value, it will give an error " Undefined index: id2"

```
<script>
var i=1;
function myFunction() {
    i++;
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("name", "id"+i);
    elem = document.getElementById("hide_specific");
   elem.appendChild(x);

}
</script>


<body>
<?php 
$submission="";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){$submission=$_POST["id2"];} 
?>

<table>
<form action="" method="POST">

<tr>
<td>
<div  id="hide_specific"><input type="text" name="id1" ><span       onClick="myFunction()">Add</span></div>

</td>
</tr>

<tr> <td><input type="submit" name="set" value="Set"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<?php echo $submission; ?></td></tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: try `isset` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Checked this question in my localhost, and used firebug.. Found that form get closed in table(form without dynamically created inputs,id2,id3 etc). Thats why POST values are not getting.Your script is absolutely fine. Try to add form tag before table.** Code shown below

```
<body>
<?php
$submission="";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){$submission=$_POST["id2"];}
?>
<form action="" method="post">  <!-- ######### OPEN FORM TAG BEFORE TABLE -->
<table>


        <tr>
            <td>
                <div  id="hide_specific"><input type="text" name="id1" ><span       onClick="myFunction()">Add</span></div>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr> <td><input type="submit" name="set" value="Set"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
                <?php echo $submission; ?></td></tr>


</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST["id2"];` get value from input NAME not ID :)